# Помогите решить вопрос с ошибкой, core-js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, core

При попытке запустить `npm run serve`, выдает ошибку

```
 Failed to compile with 2 errors
       20:39:07

This dependency was not found:

* core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js, ./src/store/modules/UserAuth.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js
```

Как положено по инструкции запускаю `npm install --save core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js`
выбивает новые ошибки

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mr.salco\Desktop\control-food-main\core-js\modules\es.object.to-string.js/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mr.salco\Desktop\control-food-main\core-js\modules\es.object.to-string.js\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mr.salco\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-10T17_41_48_249Z-debug.log
```

Чего только не пробовал, и понижать корс, и переустанавливал ничего не понимает, в гугле пересмотрел все ссылки ничего не помогло. Выдает те-же ошибки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вроде описал же, привел ошибки которые выводит и описал что сделал для решения

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в зависимости и установите сам `core-js`, а не тот файл, о котором идёт речь в ошибке. Если же `core-js` у вас уже есть - убедитесь что функционала его версии достаточно для того, что вы реализуете.